# How to align but unwrap BibTeX entries in Emacs

Tags: bibtex, emacs

The `bibtex-fill-entry` (<kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-q</kbd>) command of Emacs's BibTeX-Mode automatically aligns and wraps messily formatted BibTeX entries.  For example, it can take an entry like

```
@Article{smith1980,
author = {John Smith},
  title = {How I Weave Baskets Underwater},
 journal =  {Journal of
  Underwater Basket
Weaving and Nonsensical Latin Placeholder Texts},
  year = 1980,
abstract = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.},
}
```

and beautify it into

```
@Article{smith1980,
  author =       {John Smith},
  title =        {How I Weave Baskets Underwater},
  journal =      {Journal of Underwater Basket Weaving and Nonsensical
                  Latin Placeholder Texts},
  year =         1980,
  abstract =     {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                  elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                  nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
                  ex ea commodo consequat.  Duis aute irure dolor in
                  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                  deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.},
}
```

I like the fact that the fields and values are aligned, but I would prefer it if the values were not word-wrapped.  That is, I would prefer it if the output of `bibtex-fill-entry` on the above example were

```
@Article{smith1980,
  author =   {John Smith},
  title =    {How I Weave Baskets Underwater},
  journal =  {Journal of Underwater Basket Weaving and Nonsensical Latin Placeholder Texts},
  year =     1980,
  abstract = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.},
}
```

This allows me to more easily browse long BibTeX files with `toggle-truncate-lines`, or with any other text editor that truncates rather than wraps long lines.  Is there any way I can configure BibTeX-Mode to do this?

Comment: This is more a question towards emacs than BibTeX.  Maybe the emacs.SE-Group will be more adequate?  Chances are, that there will be a better answer in shorter time?

Comment: Maybe http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24885/align-indent-in-bibtex-file is nearly the function, you are looking for?

Comment: @Jan: I don't think so.  I do want to avail myself of all the other formatting that `bibtex-fill-entry` does, such as removing extraneous braces.  I just don't want it to wrap lines.  From what I can tell, the function you linked to performs indentation only – I don't think it even bothers unwrapping lines, let alone any other tweaking.

Comment: Nice to know about that functionality. I'm using [JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/) for entry formatting, When an entry is changed, JabRef reformats the whole entry. There is also a button "push-to-application" for getting \cite{key} into emacs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set `fill-column` to something ridiculously large (like 999999).

The command <kbd>C-x f</kbd> (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `set-fill-column` <kbd>RET</kbd>) does this (prompts for a number).

To get this as default, add this to your `.emacs` file (or whatever has this function in your Emacs):

```lisp
(add-hook 'bibtex-mode-hook
             (lambda () (setq fill-column 999999)))
```

Comment: I don't quite follow, what do you mean by `^X` here?

Comment: He means `C-x` or Control+X.

Comment: @Psychonaut but normally `C-x` is a prefix. I usually use `M-x set-variable RET fill-column` to set this value. So I was curious if there was an easier method

Comment: Well, now you've got one.  Or at least, I do – `C-x f` works for me, as does putting the hook in my `.emacs.d/init.el` file.

Comment: Great idea, Piet!  And so simple!

Comment: Nice, did not know the `C-x f` shortcut